# Framebuffer quad problem on window resize

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm following a tutorial on learnOpenGL site regarding Framebuffers which work fine at default resolution.

But whenever I resize my window, the framebuffer quad gets offset terribly. For instance if I expand the window bigger the framebuffer looks zoomed in and if I shrink my window there's gaps on the top and right. Here is a screenshot with 1 as default window, 2 as stretched big and 3 shrunk down after resize:

[image]

I did read that I have to call glViewport again but where exactly do I call this? This is my framebuffer callback I've been using:

```
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

And my framebuffer creation in main:

```
// configure framebuffer here //
unsigned int hdrFBO;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &hdrFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, hdrFBO);
// create color attachment texture buffer
unsigned int colorBuffer;
glGenTextures(1, &colorBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer, 0);
    
// create depth buffer (renderbuffer) 
unsigned int rboDepth;
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
// check status
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "Framebuffer not complete!" << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Minor update, I was told to add `glTexImage2D` and I added that in my framebuffer_size_callback function here:

```
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

}
```

Now when I resize it smaller it resizes correctly, but on making the window larger it seems to cut off and now black gaps?

[image]

Comment: IIRC you have to call `glTexImage2D` on resize to resize the framebuffer's backing texture size.

Comment: @van dench, You mean I have to call `glTexImage2D` again inside the framebuffer callback?

Comment: Well that's peculiar. Now when I shrink the window it resizes perfectly, but when I make it large, it looks like the 3rd screenshot but much larger.

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone is interested, @van dench helped with half of the solution. The reason why the resize on larger didn't work was because the depth attachment needed to be updated as well as the initial color attachment.

Both are required and you cannot leave one or the other out. So in my `framebuffer_size_callback` that's what I added and now the framebuffer adjusts on any resize and what a brainfully brutal problem to figure out.

```
void framebuffer_size_callback(...)
{
  // color buffer attachment here
  glTexImage2D(...);
  // and depth buffer attachment
  glRenderBuffer(...);
}
```

This question is solved thank you.